# 'Assigned to' option in Inbound e-mails

Tags: inbound-email

We're trying the inbound e-mail to activity functionality and it works fine.

The only limitation until now is that the 'source' and 'assigned to' contact seems to be the same.

We need to have a process that adds an activity assigned to 'C', created by 'A' with contact 'B'.

Is this possible out of the box? Would you use a CiviRule to change assignee?

(we've been through documentation and SE and couldn't find such a situation, that seemed at first obvious to me)

Answer (score 1):

Would https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_emailProcessor/ work? It will let you update the assignee on the activity after it gets saved.

e.g.

```
function myextension_civicrm_emailProcessor( $type, &$params, $mail, &$result, $action = null ) {
  if ($type != 'activity') {
    return;
  }
  $contact_id = 36377; // this is contact C
  $params = array(
    1 => array($contact_id, 'Integer'),
    2 => array($result['id'], 'Integer'),
    3 => array(CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey('CRM_Activity_BAO_ActivityContact', 'record_type_id', 'Activity Assignees'), 'Integer'),
  );
  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("UPDATE civicrm_activity_contact SET contact_id = %1 WHERE activity_id = %2 AND record_type_id=%3", $params);
  // or use api if preferred
}
```

Comment: thanks Dave, this means I don't need to dig further in some hidden front setting. We'll use this hook instead.